# Getting "cannot init crypto" while deploying hyperledger fabric peer to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy one peer hyperledger fabric network setup to Kubernetes on GCP and while deploying peer I a getting  error -

> "Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /var/msp folder"

I tried mounting the msp material but it is not working

This is peer configs -

> apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment metadata:   name: peer0 spec:
>   replicas: 1   selector:
>       matchLabels:
>         app: peer0   template:
>       metadata:
>         labels:
>           app: peer0
>           tier: backend
>           track: stable
>       spec:
>         hostAliases:
>         - ip: "10.128.0.3"
>           hostnames:
>           - "peer0.example.com"
>         - ip: "10.128.0.3"
>           hostnames:
>           - "couchdb0"
>         - ip: "10.128.0.4"
>           hostnames:
>             - "orderer0.orderer.com"
>         nodeSelector:
>           id: peer
>         containers:
>         - name: peer0
>           image: "hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.0"
>           ports:
>             - name: peer0-port
>               containerPort: 30002
>             - name: peer0-chaincode
>               containerPort: 30003
>             - name: peer0-event
>               containerPort: 30004
>           workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
>           command: ["peer"]
>           args: ["node","start"]
>           env:
>             - name: CORE_VM_ENDPOINT
>               value: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT
>               value: "true"
>             - name: CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE
>               value: "bridge"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_ID
>               value: "peer0.example.com"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
>               value: "peer0.example.com:30002"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
>               value: "peer0.example.com:30002"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS
>               value: "0.0.0.0:30003"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP
>               value: "0.0.0.0:30002"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS
>               value: "0.0.0.0:30002"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_EVENTS_ADDRESS
>               value: "0.0.0.0:30004"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
>               value: "exampleMSP"
>             - name: CORE_LOGGING_GOSSIP
>               value: "INFO"
>             - name: CORE_LOGGING_PEER_GOSSIP
>               value: "INFO"
>             - name: CORE_LOGGING_MSP
>               value: "INFO"
>             - name: CORE_LOGGING_POLICIES
>               value: "DEBUG"
>             - name: CORE_LOGGING_CAUTHDSL
>               value: "DEBUG"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
>               value: "false"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
>               value: "true"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
>               value: "false"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
>               value: "true"
>             - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE
>               value: "CouchDB"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
>               value: "false"
>             - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS
>               value: "couchdb0:30005"
>             - name: ORDERER_URL
>               value: "orderer0.orderer.com:30001"
>             - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME
>               value: ""
>             - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
>               value: ""
>             - name: CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT
>               value: "true"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH
>               value: "/var/production"
>             - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
>               #value: "/var/msp"
>               value: "/var/msp"
>           volumeMounts:
>             - name: peer0-volume
>               mountPath: /var
>             - name: host
>               mountPath: /var/run
>
> ```
>   volumes:
>     - name: peer0-volume
>       #persistentVolumeClaim:
>        # claimName: peer0-pvc
>     - name: host
>       hostPath:
>         path: /var/run
> ```

Comment: I resolved it , it was happening due to files are not getting mount inside the container , I have added separate mount points for that and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resolution approach. I have moved your comment to the answer area as a community wiki, in case someone else experiences the same issue.

Comment: "blockchain" and "google-kubernetes-engine" tags appear to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing James comment

> "I resolved it , it was happening due to files not getting mount inside the container , I have added separate mount points for that and it worked fine."

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to try kubechain from npm.

Comment: kindly consider adding more details for your answer

Comment: yeah, can you share any resource,links or tutorial for that.